# Can't knit the R file that I am trying to make

Tags: r, knitr

So I have a document where I'm trying to knit, but I get an error where it says that

```
Error: object 'r' not found
Execution halted
```

Here is my full code:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Test Test"
date: "05.15.2022"
output: 
  html_document: 
    toc: yes
    toc_float: yes
editor_options: 
  markdown: 
    wrap: sentence
---

# Header

##chunks

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE,warning = FALSE, error = FALSE)
```

```{r}
sapply(cars,class)
```
````

Any help? I am really new to R.

Comment: Is the filename extension `.Rmd` or `.md`? Is your system configured to use quatro? (a recent language-less-agnostic multi-language knitter ... if you don't recognize it, then it is unlikely you're using quatro)

Comment: @r2evans my file extension is .Rmd and I don't recognize quatro

Comment: Are you using RStudio? If yes...are you clicking the "Knit" box? (as opposed to run) Is the file extension .Rmd? Are your Rstudio and R installations recent?  In any case your script copied into tem.RMD in my installation and knitted to html produces a file just fine. So your code is OK, something is off elsewhere.

Comment: That's tem.Rmd. I am running the most recent R and RStudio versions on Windows 11.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error message. Your `MWE` runs well on my window machine.

Comment: Are you sure `knitr` is installed on your machine?

Comment: I deleted my knitr package and tried to knit the tem.Rmd file. Lots of errors of course, however none like the OP stated they got.